# Is $n_{\rightarrow\infty}\overline{\frac{n}{\phi (n)}}$ unbounded?

Tags: number-theory

Does a $\limsup_{n\to\infty}$ exist for $\overline{\dfrac{n}{\phi (n)}},$ where $\phi$ is the Euler totient function, and the overbar represents the mean.

Of course $\dfrac{n}{\phi (n)}$ is unbounded, as it grows like $e^{\gamma } \log (\log (x))+\dfrac{\text{c}}{\log (\log (x))}$ for some $c\approx 3,$ where $c\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty,$ but I was wondering whether the set of (mostly, priomorial multiples) is dense enough to impose a limit on the function.

Numerical tests suggest $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\overline{\dfrac{n}{\phi (n)}}\approx 2,$ but I can't find any references to the subject. Is this realistic, or is the function unbounded?

Comment: By "mean" you mean $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{k}{\phi(k)}\,?$$

Comment: @DanielFischer yes - should I adapt?

Comment: @EricNaslund thanks for link to dup. - great answer there too (+1) :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have that holds $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{\phi\left(k\right)}=\frac{315\zeta\left(3\right)}{2\pi^{4}}n+O\left(\log\left(n\right)\right)
 $$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#cite_note-23) for reference) then $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{\phi\left(k\right)}=\frac{315\zeta\left(3\right)}{2\pi^{4}}.$$

Comment: that was quick! Thanks :)

Comment: [PDF link](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.rmjm/1250127232) for your link above - thanks for ref. - looks like an interesting read :)

Comment: That constant is close to 2 so good initial guess @martin. Its not a number I would have guessed :)

Comment: I expect the factor $\frac{315\zeta(3)}{2\pi^4}$ should be written [as in "comes from"] as $\frac{\zeta(2)\zeta(3)}{\zeta(6)}$.

Comment: @martin It's my pleasure. I'm glad that the reference is interesting for you ;)

Comment: Elegant addition there @DanielFischer.

Comment: This is also proven here on Math.StackExchange: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84708/on-the-mean-value-of-a-multiplicative-function-prove-that-sum-limits-n-leq-x/84721#84721